# How to close window prompt in Cypress

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I,m new using cypress and i need help to handling window prompt. I don,t know how to accept o cancel the following screenshot. Thank you [Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u1PQ.png)

That ptompt is impossible to select any button, has no DOM, i tried cy.contains, cy.stub

Answer (score 0):

Which version of cypress do you have?
You could try directly login without filling out the login:

```
cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `YOUR URL OF CURRENT PAGE`,
      body: {
        userName: 'yyy',
        password: 'xxx',
      },
    });
```

After that you need a cy.visit('URL AFTER LOGIN')